# FFmpeg can't properly splice my avi/mp3 audio files?

Tags: ffmpeg

**ATTEMPT #1** on a mp3 laced avi file:

I want to splice the first part of a movie I have. Here is the command I used:

```
ffmpeg -i file.avi -ss 0 -t 90 -acodec copy -vcodec copy output-4.avi
```

Here is the result of the command:

```
FFmpeg version SVN-r0.5.1-4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --disable-stripping --disable-vhook --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0
  libavcodec    52.20. 1 / 52.20. 1
  libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
  libavfilter    0. 4. 0 /  0. 4. 0
  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Mar  4 2010 12:35:30, gcc: 4.4.3
[NULL @ 0x92e0570]Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 29.98 (65535/2186) -> 29.97 (2997/100)
Input #0, avi, from 'file.avi':
  Duration: 01:30:57.84, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1075 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 512x288 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 29.98 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 32 kb/s
File 'output-4.avi' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, avi, to 'output-4.avi':
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 512x288 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: 0x0055, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 32 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Press [q] to stop encoding
frame= 2698 fps=  0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    8995kB time=90.02 bitrate= 818.5kbits/s    
video:7342kB audio:1490kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 1.847673%
```

There is an inconsistency. The output of the audio is `0x0055` whereas the input is `mp3`. Why is this so? So I not have the proper `mp3` package?

When I open the video, the audio is clearly messed up as it sounds very distorted, like conjoined channels of audio. The video seems intact.

**ATTEMPT #2** on a mp2 laced mpg file:

As a comparison, I was able to splice an mpeg that had mp2 audio fine:

Original command:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mpg -ss 15 -t 60 -acodec copy -vcodec copy output-2.mpg
```

Result:

```
FFmpeg version SVN-r0.5.1-4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --disable-stripping --disable-vhook --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0
  libavcodec    52.20. 1 / 52.20. 1
  libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
  libavfilter    0. 4. 0 /  0. 4. 0
  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Mar  4 2010 12:35:30, gcc: 4.4.3
Input #0, mpeg, from 'file.mpg':
  Duration: 00:15:36.76, start: 0.339000, bitrate: 1394 kb/s
    Stream #0.0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p, 352x240 [PAR 200:219 DAR 880:657], 1150 kb/s, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0.1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 224 kb/s
File 'output-2.mpg' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, mpeg, to 'output-2.mpg':
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p, 352x240 [PAR 200:219 DAR 880:657], q=2-31, 1150 kb/s, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 224 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Press [q] to stop encoding
[mpeg @ 0x8b0a1a0]buffer underflow i=1 bufi=0 size=731
frame= 1799 fps=  0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   10154kB time=75.42 bitrate=1103.0kbits/s    
video:8429kB audio:1651kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.724915%
```

**EDIT** #1: As per fedeli here is the output of ffmpeg -formats | grep mp3:

```
ffmpeg -formats | grep mp3
FFmpeg version SVN-r0.5.1-4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --disable-stripping --disable-vhook --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0
  libavcodec    52.20. 1 / 52.20. 1
  libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
  libavfilter    0. 4. 0 /  0. 4. 0
  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Mar  4 2010 12:35:30, gcc: 4.4.3
 DE mp3             MPEG audio layer 3
 D A    mp3             MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)
 D A    mp3adu          ADU (Application Data Unit) MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)
 D A    mp3on4          MP3onMP4
 text2movsub remove_extra noise mov2textsub mp3decomp mp3comp mjpegadump imxdump h264_mp4toannexb dump_extra
```

Comment: What is the output of `ffmpeg -formats | grep mp3`?

Comment: updated question with output.

Comment: can you select mp3 as an output stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd actually want the output from:

```
ffmpeg -codecs | grep libmp3lame
```

if it's not there you're most likely going to have to recompile and add the missing:

```
--enable-libmp3lame
```

and for good measure:

```
--enable-gpl --enable-version3
```

Instead of -acodec copy etc... what happens if you simply do:

```
ffmpeg -i file.avi -t 90 output.avi
```